# Importing CSS is ending up with an error

Tags: css

Recently I've got in to [this website](http://thecodeplayer.com/), and found couple of totally cool designs, but in some of them, in the CSS part there is a snippet of code for importing like this ;

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
```

Whenever, I copy this in to my own CSS file, it ends up with an error saying ;

> Imported style sheets are not checked in direct input and file upload
>   mode ( level 0 )

Does anyone have any idea what's the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're just trying to validate your CSS file using the W3C validator, and it's letting you know that it's not going to validate the imported style sheet (Google's). It's not an error, just some information for you.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I found the issue some where else,