# Imported style sheets're not checked in direct input and file uploads mode (level 0)

Tags: css, aptana

I have just done  `@import url('../image.css') screen;` in another CSS file. However, I have got `imported style sheets are not checked in direct input and file uploads mode (level 0)`. I don't understand the reason why this warning is emitted by Aptana. What should I do so that the problem will be solved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing CSS is ending up with an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25946111/importing-css-is-ending-up-with-an-error)